# SendVoteRequest is not working properly as doesn't vote on the poll

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I tried to vote on the anonymous telegram poll
but when I sent a vote request from the client to the telethon, it didn't work properly. and at the end, there will be no vote on the poll

Telethon documentation ref : https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/send_vote.html

```py
#Question : Are you OK?
#options:  1. Yes
#          2. No
#          3. Maybe
#          4. None

async def send_PollAnswer(client, chat_id, message_id):
result = await client(functions.messages.SendVoteRequest(
            peer=chat_id,
            msg_id=message_id,
            options=[b'Yes']
        ))
        print(result.stringify())
```

let me know

I expected an increase in voting, but their is nothing except this error:

ever closed the connection: 0 bytes read on a total of 8 expected bytes
Unhandled error while receiving data

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:UsershammaAppDataLocalProgramsPythonPython311Libsite-packagestelethonnetworkmtprotosender.py,", line 505, in _recv_loop
    body = await self._connection.recv()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:UsershammaAppDataLocalProgramsPythonPython311Libsite-packagestelethonnetworkconnectionconnection.py,", line 304, in recv
    raise err
  File "C:UsershammaAppDataLocalProgramsPythonPython311Libsite-packagestelethonnetworkconnectionconnection.py,", line 335, in _recv_loop
    data = await self._recv()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:UsershammaAppDataLocalProgramsPythonPython311Libsite-packagestelethonnetworkconnectionconnection.py,", line 374, in _recv
    return await self._codec.read_packet(self._reader)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:UsershammaAppDataLocalProgramsPythonPython311Libsite-packagestelethonnetworkconnectiontcpfull.py,", line 25, in read_packet
packet_len_seq = await reader.readexactly(8)  # 4 and 4
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: The error you posted seems to indicate the connection was closed. Are you able to use other requests?

Answer (score 0):

After a long effort, I found the bug in the SendVoteRequest parameter. Instead of passing the option, we have to pass the index number only.

```
    async def send_PollAnswer(client,chat_id, message_id):
        try:
            await client(functions.messages.SendVoteRequest(
                peer=chat_id,
                msg_id=message_id,
                options=[b'0']
            ))
        
        except:
            print("Error found")
```